# Confusion. about the precise definition on $\infty$ in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, infinity

In the complex analysis, we define a point $\infty$ on the complex plane. Then the textbook claims that (a) None of the semi-plane (all the points on one side of a fixed line) contains the $\infty$
(b) every line goes through the $\infty$. But (b) implies that $\infty  \in l$, $\forall$ line $l$. And we can now pick a line contained in the semi-plane by letting the line be parallel to the boundary of the semi-plane. Then $\infty$ is a member of the semi-plane, contradicts what (a) said. But what is wrong in the above argument? And what's the precise definition of $\infty  \in S$, $S$ a subset of $C\cup \{\infty\}$?

Comment: In another context, plane projective geometry, there is a whole line "at infinity", not a single point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) and (b) are really definitions, though they may not be phrased that way. The textbook is saying that when they use the word "line" in discussing a subset of $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$, it will include $\infty$ (i.e., it will include an ordinary line in $\mathbb{C}$ together with $\infty$), while when they use the word "semi-plane" it will not include $\infty$ (it will include just the ordinary semi-plane in $\mathbb{C}$).

If you want a precise description of how $\infty$ is included in the complex plane, look up "stereographic projection" of the sphere to the plane. But that doesn't really change the fact that (a) and (b) are just definitions of how we use the words "line" and "semi-plane" in the context of $\mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty \}$.

For a justification for why this is a reasonable definition, you can think that since a line includes $\infty$, then a semi-plane is one component of the complement of the line, so the semi-plane will not include $\infty$. This does have the consequence that a line (extended to $\mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty \}$) parallel to the boundary of a semi-plane, will no longer be contained in the semi-plane (which is really what your argument shows), which may seem weird, but there is no logical contradiction.

Comment: Thanks. If you do not mind my further further bothering, I am reading Ahlfors recently. And I raised this question since the book defined simply connected space by saying that its complement wrt $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ is connected. So how to define a connected set on $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$? And this may have something to do with the definition of the open set on $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$.

Comment: Topologically, $\mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty \}$ should be regarded as a sphere, and $\mathbb{C}$ embedded in the sphere by stereographic projection.

Comment: Thanks. So I think that a point set $A\subset \mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ with $\infty$ a member is connected if for any point $x\in A-\{\infty\}$ there is a continuous curve $\Omega\subset A$ such that it starts from $x$ and there is a point sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_n\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, so that on the sphere, any point in $A$ is connected to the north pole with a continuous curve contained in $A$, and then any two point in $A$ can be connected using a continuous curve in $A$. Is this definition reasonable?

Answer (score 1):

The *Riemann sphere* is the one-point campactification of the complex plane (or $\Bbb R^2$).

It's well known that the standard $2$-sphere $S^2$ minus a point is homeomorphic, indeed diffeomorphic, to $\Bbb R^2$.

Anyway $\infty $ can be thought of as the added (or subtracted)  point.